# Flutter - How to replace with the same character in list<String>

Tags: flutter, dart

i have list string like this :
`List<String> alphabet = [a,b,c];`

then i add same string like : `alphabet.add(a);`

the result is `[a,b,c,a]`

> the question is, How do I make sure the values ​​in the string list
> remain the same `[a,b,c]` because the value a already exists in the string list

Answer (score 3):

Use `Set` (https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.1.3/dart-core/Set-class.html):

```dart
Set<String> alphabet = Set();
alphabet.add("a");
alphabet.add("a"); // Won't be added
alphabet.add("b");

print(alphabet);

// Result: {a, b}
```

Sets are like lists but automatically ignores duplicates, the best (and suggested) solution for your needs.

Also, you can convert your set to `List` using `alphabet.toList()`;

You can also keep your current `List` with duplicates and then convert it to `Set` when you need to remove duplicates:

```dart
List<String> example = ["a", "a", "b"];
Set<String> alphabet = example.toSet();
print(alphabet.toList());
// Result: [a, b]
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to check if the character is already contained before adding it.

```
if(!alphabet.contains(newChar)){
    alphabet.add(newChar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `List` for the case, you can use the `Set` concept in programming that serves as a container for a collection of unique values. Unlike other data structures like lists or arrays, a Set does not allow duplicate elements. This means that each element stored in a Set is distinct.

```dart
void main() {

  Set alphabet = {"a", "b", "c"};

  alphabet.add("d");

  alphabet.add("a");

  print(alphabet.toList());
}
```

Output will be `[a, b, c, d]`.